# Setting textbox value in struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have a form in Struts 1.2 where I have text boxes (text box created using struts html tag) . I have retrieved the values for this text box from data base and then put in session attribute (`session.setAttribute("UserInfo",userinfoobj)`) now   I wants to get values from session attribute and set this value as value of text box

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to use a `form-bean` to hold the values of your input fields and then bind this form bean to your JSP page using struts configuration. Populate this form bean and then set it in `session` or `request` scope. Struts will handle the values (for capturing and rendering) behind the scene automatically if you use appropriate struts tags.

Pls google how to use `ActionForm` with struts 1.x

EDIT: here is simple example on how to do this http://www.raistudies.com/struts-1/login-form-with-struts-1/

Comment: Hi Bimlesh,Thanks for your support. My question is slight different. I wants to populate my textbox with value that is in session attribute.

Comment: Why are you keeping in session directly? You could keep in the form bean. I don't understand your application design. Text box can be directly mapped to a property in the form bean. However, if you just wish to access the value stored in the session, look at struts <bean:write> tag

Comment: Hi Bimalesh, Please suggest how can we set the value of textbox using bean write tag.

Comment: You cannot use both struts tag `<html:text>` and `<bean:write>` together. However, you can use normal html markup like `<input type="text" value='<bean:write name="XXX" />' >

Answer (score 0):

Use `OGNL` stack.

Use this: `value="parameters.<your request variable name>"`.

Comment: Value="parameters" can take only the string type value. Then how to add bean value in this field.